# clear network share credentials in win 2012

Tags: samba, windows-server-2012

I am fiddling around with a network share (samba, but that should not be relevant) in win 2012 server. As I am changing access rights frequently, I would like to have a simple method to revoke the credentials on the client side (I am assuming they get cached somewhere, since they are are still "active" after restarting the samba server), so that I have to "reconnect". Currently I just reboot the win server, but that is rather tedious and time consuming. Ideally, there would be some sort of power shell command to do just the credentials removing?

I see that [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/451387/how-to-delete-cached-temporeraly-credentials-for-a-network-share-on-a-windows-ma) pretty much describes what I want, but the answers given did not help much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does `net use * /del` not accomplish what you're looking to achieve?  This *should* delete all shared network drive credentials.

Additionally, in the thread you reference there is a comment which states that you need not only delete the credentials, but delete the currently active authentication ticket by doing `klist purge` (docs: [Klist](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh134826%28v=ws.10%29.aspx))

Comment: `net use * /del` does delete all connections listed by `net use`, but I still don't have to reauthenticate. But after adding `klist purge`, it seems to work. I thought I had tried that bevor, but now it works. Thank you for insisting.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, all that method will work. But you must wait for some period of time because the Server that you connect will save your connection session. See this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/openspecification/archive/2013/03/27/smb-2-x-and-smb-3-0-timeouts-in-windows.aspx) for more information.

If you ticked the `remember my credential` at logon promo, then you can type:

```
rundll32.exe keymgr.dll KRShowKeyMgr
```

to show all your credentials.